# Поиск с помощью регулярного выражения абзацов и вставка своего абзаца после каждого найденного

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно регулярное выражение для поиска всех абзацов`(<p>....</p>)` в тексте. Также нужно вставить свой конкретный абзац после каждого совпадения. Особенно важен 2й пункт.

Comment: Дайте однозначное определение термину "Абзац".

Comment: это не биржа фрилансеров.

Comment: дал определение абзацу

Comment: А как код должен себя вести для вложенных абзацев (`<p><p>...</p></p>`)?

Comment: у меня нет вложенных абзацов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решил задачу использование `explode()` и `implode()`.

Comment: кастыль же используйте simpleHtml или другую библиотеку для построения dom дерева